# Erro ao criar lista com NgFor em angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Fala pessoal ,tudo bem ?

Estou com problema ao usar o *Ngfor no angular para criar uma lista de card em um componente externo , eu busquei em alguns blogs e até mesmo no stackoverglow sobre mas não cheguei nenhuma solução , alguma dizem para importa component browsermoduler e commonModule na minha aplicação mas eu já fiz isso no componente principal (app) porém no component externo eu não consigo importar.

Codigo do componente externo :

```
import { Component, NgModule, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista-de-posts',
  templateUrl: './lista-de-posts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista-de-posts.component.css']
})




export class ListaDePostsComponent implements OnInit {
 
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
      // this.items = fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=1')
    //   .then(response => response.json())
    //   .then(json => {
    //     //this.items = json;
    //     return json;
    //   })
     this.array.toString

  }

 
   array = [
    {
      guid: '900ea552-ef68-42cc-b6a6-b8c4dff10fb7',
      age: 32,
      name: 'Powers Schneider',
    },
    {
      guid: '880381d3-8dca-4aed-b207-b3b4e575a15f',
      age: 25,
      name: 'Adrian Lawrence',
    },
    {
      guid: '87b47684-c465-4c51-8c88-3f1a1aa2671b',
      age: 32,
      name: 'Boyer Stanley',
    }
  ]
  
}
```

Html :

```
<br />
<div class="section-header home-title"><h2 class="page-title">Recentes Post</h2><p class="sub-title">O que tem de novo?</p></div>
<div class="container text-center">
    <div class="row">
      <ul>
        <li *ngfor="let item of array">
          <div  class="col-6">
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=17F2uR0bOuw5jjFaXhus2uF6XcdcFmz6g" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">O porque arte marcial [e importa para o homem?</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1BYThn0oucZKx-yQc-oxE4vmNvksD6rOD/view?usp=share_link" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                  <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
      
      <!-- <div class="col-6">
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTVjMmE0NDMtNjE5My00YTY4LWE1NWQtYzY3OWI5NzgwZjU5XkEyXkFqcGdeQTNwaW5nZXN0._V1_.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card mb-3">
            <img src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTVjMmE0NDMtNjE5My00YTY4LWE1NWQtYzY3OWI5NzgwZjU5XkEyXkFqcGdeQTNwaW5nZXN0._V1_.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
              <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div> -->

</div>
```

Imagem de Erro :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o *ngfor em `<li *ngfor="let item of array">`   troque para `*ngFor` e tente novamente

Answer (score -2):

Você está importando

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'
```

dentro do component

> ListaDePostsComponent

Você precisa importar os Modules dentro do Module onde o componente foi declarado, ex:

> ComponentsModule

Exemplo de um module em angular, as importações de modules são ordenadas no início do arquivo, e são utilizadas dentro do @NgModule na parte de imports: []

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ExampleComponent } from './example-component';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ExampleComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    providers: [],
})

export class ComponentsModule { }
```

1. Primeira possibilidade, seu module não contem CommonModule importado nos imports[]
2. Seu component onde você está usando *ngFor or *ngIf não faz parte de nenhum modulo.
3. Você pode estar digitando em vez de *ngFor, **ngFor ou *ngfor etc..
4. Se nada disso fizer sentido em seu app, reinicie sua IDE(Vs Code, IntelliJ etc..)

Comment: Eles já foram importados no componente principal como você disse em cima , porém o Ng for não continua funcionando, eu não sei se precisar chamar alguma função no typescript para que o array consiga funcionar no html

Comment: Editei pra vc a resposta adicionando outras possibilidades, mas eu acredito que seja alguma dessas.. Pq realmente não faz sentido se não for